Not able to see updates my mobile after making updates on wordpress mobile version
I'm not able to see the updated version of my website when I open it on my phone. I've cleared the coache etc but still have the same issue. Can anyone help me out?

by wordpress mobile version do you mean the WordPress app from the app store? This stack is for programmers but there's no code to work with, and no information about your site, you might be better asking this on the .org forums along with as much information about your site as you can gather
